# Windows won't boot up

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

My Dell computer has both a SSD and a HDD.

On the SSD, I have been running Windows 10 in legacy boot mode

I installed Ubuntu on my HDD. Afterwards, Ubuntu GNU GRUB for dual boot configuration was not showing up because Windows was in legacy mode, so I followed a youtube tutorial to convert Windows 10 from legacy to UEFI mode using "Paragon Partition Manager"

When my system rebooted I turned on the UEFI boot secure mode. Since then, GNU GRUB shows but only Ubuntu runs fine. Windows boot loader goes to a automatic repair loop.

I've tried repairing, reinstalling, and resetting but none of these options worked as it gave me error.

In Ubuntu it shows my SSD and HDD but now it demands the bitlocker key.

Comment: You're better off asking this question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).  Per your description, GRUB and Ubuntu work just fine, but your problem happens after GRUB hands off to the Windows boot loader. This means that your problem is with Windows and will probably need a Windows-based solution, or at the very least, require expertise from the Windows community to solve.

Comment: Best to remove Windows drive when installing Ubuntu to another drive. Install Ubuntu in the same BIOS, UEFI mode that Windows is installed in. My opinion is that this is the right place to ask questions about installing Ubuntu even if it concerns dual boot with Windows or any other OS..

Comment: Of course questions about installing Ubuntu are on topic. However this question is asking how to fix a Windows boot problem.

Comment: The problem is due to incorrectly installing Ubuntu for dual boot. The OP should have installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode if Windows was running in legacy mode. Or at least removed Window disk while installing Ubuntu and settled for pressing F8, F9 or F12 to select disk during boot.